# Why the view table use two different name of the same table?

Tags: mysql

```
   CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `pg2bikz3eqxbwgl5mybtxnawhccpgi`.`recalls_after_reserv` AS 
    select 
    `a`.`office_id` AS `office_id`,
    `a`.`patient_id` AS `patient_id`,
    `a`.`id` AS `recalls_id`,
    `a`.`came_at` AS `came_at`,
    `a`.`memo` AS `memo`,
    `a`.`noticed_with` AS `noticed_with`,
    `a`.`recall_menu` AS `recall_menu`,
    `a`.`recall_type_id` AS `recall_type_id`,
    `a`.`recalled_at` AS `recalled_at`,
    `a`.`recalls_at` AS `recalls_at`,
    `a`.`required_time` AS `required_time`,
    `a`.`reservation_id` AS `bef_reservation_id`,
    (case when isnull(`c`.`id`) then `d`.`id` else `c`.`id` end) AS `reservation_id`,
    (case when isnull(`c`.`id`) then `d`.`starts_at` else `c`.`starts_at` end) AS **starts_at**,
    (case when isnull(`c`.`id`) then `d`.`checked_in_at` else `c`.`checked_in_at` end) AS `checked_in_at`,
    (case when isnull(`c`.`id`) then `d`.`created_at` else `c`.`created_at` end) AS `created_at`,
    (case when isnull(`c`.`id`) then `d`.`deleted_at` else `c`.`deleted_at` end) AS `deleted_at`,
    (case when isnull(`c`.`id`) then `d`.`menu_id` else `c`.`menu_id` end) AS `next_menu_id`,
    (case when isnull(`c`.`id`) then `d`.`cancel_type` else `c`.`cancel_type` end) AS `cancel_type`,
    `a`.`menu_id` AS `menu_id`,
    `a`.`menu2_id` AS `menu2_id`,
    `a`.`menu3_id` AS `menu3_id`,
    (case when isnull(`c`.`id`) then NULL else `a`.`created_reservation_id` end) AS `created_reservation_id`,
    `z`.`datetime_disp` AS `datetime_disp` 
    from (
    ((`pg2bikz3eqxbwgl5mybtxnawhccpgi`.`recalls` `a` 
    left join `pg2bikz3eqxbwgl5mybtxnawhccpgi`.**reservations** `c` on(((`a`.`created_reservation_id` = `c`.`id`) and (isnull(`c`.`deleted_at`)
 or ((`c`.`deleted_at` is not null) and (`c`.`cancel_type` = 'patient')))))) 
    left join `pg2bikz3eqxbwgl5mybtxnawhccpgi`.`recalls_after_start_at` `z` on((`a`.`id` = `z`.`recalls_id`))) 
    left join `pg2bikz3eqxbwgl5mybtxnawhccpgi`.**reservations** `d` on(((`z`.`office_id` = `d`.`office_id`) 
    and (`z`.`patient_id` = `d`.`patient_id`) 
    and (`z`.`starts_at` = `d`.`starts_at`) 
    and (isnull(`z`.`menu_id`) or (`z`.`menu_id` = `d`.`menu_id`)) 
    and (isnull(`d`.`deleted_at`) or ((`d`.`deleted_at` is not null) and (`d`.`cancel_type` = 'patient')))))
    ) 
    where isnull(`a`.`deleted_at`);
```

In this view table, the reservation table has two name : c and d.
that's why ? What is the difference ? if you think it is two wide to answer, can you give some links for me to learn these SQL?

Comment: Did you ask the person that created the view? They *probably* are meant to be different types of reservation, or something like that

Comment: The query joins the reservations table twice on different conditions, the aliases c and d are required to distinguish the two joins. When the id from the first join (alias c) is null then values are retrieved from the columns in the second join (alias d) otherwise from same columns in the first join.